# partial view model returns null from the main view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to view two separate tables without relations between them in the same view. the idea is to create an account and add it to the account table and add multiple lobs and add it to the lob table. so I made two partial views for each one. I made a ViewModel that has an instance of the account and a list of the lob. the problem is in the main view, the partial model returns null. I don't know why. any ideas?
I appreciate your help.

```
@model Manage_account.Models.AccountVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/AccountOrOU/PartialViews/_Account.cshtml", Model);}
            </div>
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/AccountOrOU/PartialViews/_Lob.cshtml", Model);}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Partial view:**

```
@model Manage_account.Models.AccountOrOU


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="ViewData">
        <h4>AccountOrOU</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountOrOUID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountOrOUName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountOrOUName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountOrOUName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Model:**

```
 public class AccountVM
    {
        public AccountOrOU AccountOrOU { get; set; }
        public List<Lob> lobs { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(AccountVM vM)
        {if (vM != null)
            {
                var myAccount = db.AccountOrOUs.ToList();
                foreach (var acc in myAccount)
                {
                    acc.AccountOrOUID= vM.AccountOrOU.AccountOrOUID ;
                    acc.AccountOrOUName=vM.AccountOrOU.AccountOrOUName ;
                    acc.DepartmentID=vM.AccountOrOU.DepartmentID ;
                    db.AccountOrOUs.Add(acc);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'the partial model returns null?' can you pin point where are you getting null?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear `@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/AccountOrOU/PartialViews/_Account.cshtml", ViewData.Model.AccountOrOU);}` the error pops out here as the model i'm passing as the model used inside the partialview is null.

Comment: I guess your ```ViewData.Model.lOBs``` is the one returning null as the property name is ```lob``` as I can see?

Comment: no @JalalShahoud . the render of the other partial view I commented it. the only render partial now is for the account partial view. Is my logic wrong ? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I see now, okay, the model is null and that's why it's not being accepted, my suggestion would be that you create a default constructor for your ```AccountVM``` and initialize ```AccountOrU``` inside that so that you wouldn't get null on that

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the part `ViewData.Model.AccountOrOU` and added instead `Model` and it worked  . but honestly, I don't know the difference here. the first one I used once and was working. I don't know why not working with this project?