# viewmodel passes to controller null from the main create view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked so many times but checked all the answers with my code and I have no naming conflict and I pass the ID as a hidden field and yet the ViewModel passes to the controller as null.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766844/partial-view-model-returns-null-from-the-main-view) is the link of my project idea and snippet of the code. What might I be missing?

Comment: Can you please show the full error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi @KEmery, the issue here has no error message. I just debugged the create post method and found the ViewModel pass as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and copied your code into the project. I, too, recieved a null model when trying to create. It took a few changes to fix it for me. I had to add 'Model.AccountOrOU' as the passed in model to the partial. I had to initialize the model in the controller for the Create Index. I also had to change the name attribute on the properties of the AccountOrOU model in the view. Here is my code ->

Index.cshtml

```
@model AccountVM

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAccount", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Account.cshtml", Model.AccountOrOU);}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

_Account.cshtml

```
@model AccountOrOU

    <div class="form-horizontal" id="ViewData">
        <h4>Account Partial</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="AccountOrOU.Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test2.Models
{

    public class AccountVM
    {
        public AccountVM()
        {
            AccountOrOU = new AccountOrOU();
        }
        public AccountOrOU AccountOrOU { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountOrOU
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            AccountVM blah = new AccountVM();
            return View(blah);
        }

        public IActionResult SaveAccount(AccountVM input)
        {
            return View("Index", input);
        }
```

Comment: I apologize if my code was incomplete. I just added the return to the index but in the debugging, I never go there. my point of the question is why the `AccountVM vM` passed from the view to the controller as null.

Comment: Could nested forms be the issue. You open a form tag in your Create view then open another form in your partial.

Comment: no Ben, I just removed it and left the form in the main create view and still the model passes as null. 

Comment: My last attempt -> You are passing the AccountVM model to the Create View. You are then passing the AccountVM model into your partial. However, the partial is expecting the AccountOrOU model. Instead of passing "Model" to the partial, try passing "Model.AccountOrOU".

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm sorry I didn't reply yesterday, I went home. I'm going to try your answer and respond to you as soon as I try it. thank you for helping me.

Comment: hi Ben, I changed the model class similar to what you did and also the naming and it worked .but I removed the lob list for the moment because it passes as null  and I'm going to figure out a solution for it now. Thank you , really 

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Account.cshtml"}
```

Then change this line:

```
<input type="text" name="AccountOrOU.Name" class="form-control" />
```

to this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccountOrOU.Name, new { @class="form-control" })
```